# How to convert method calls to postfix notation?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, expression, postfix-notation

I'm writing a compiler for a javascript like language for fun. aka I'm learning about the wheel so I make one for myself and trying to find out everything but now I got stuck.

I know that shunting yard algorithm is a nice one when parsing simple infix expressions. I was able to figure out how to extend this algorithm for prefix and postfix operators too and also able to parse simple functions.

For example: `2+3*a(3,5)+b(3,5)` turns into `2 3 <G> 3 5 a () * + <G> 3 5 b () +`

(`<G>` is a guard token that is pushed on the stack it will store the return address etc. `()` is the call command that calls the function on the top of the stack that pops out the necessary amount of arguments and pushes back the result on return.)

If the function name is just one token I can simply mark it as function symbol if directly followed by a parenthesis. During the process if I encounter a function symbol I push it on the operator stack and pop it out when I finished converting the parameters.

This is working so far.

But if I add the option to have member functions, the `.` operator. The things get more tricky. For example I want to convert the `a.b.c(12)+d.e.f(34)` I can't mark c and f to be functions because `a.b.c` and `d.e.f` are functions. If I start my parser on an expression like this the result will be `a b . <G> 12 c () . d e . <G> 34 f () .` Which is obviously wrong. I want it to be `<G> 12 a b . c . () <G> 34 d e . f. ()` Which appears correct.
But of curse I can make the things more complicated if I add some parentheses: `(a.b.c)()`. Or I make a function that returns a function which I call again: `f(a,b)(c,d)`.

Is there an easy way handle these tricky situations?

Answer (score 0):

A problem of your approach is that you treat object and its member as two separate tokens separated by `.`. Classical Shunting yard algorithm knows nothing about OOP and relies on single token for function call. So the first way to resolve you problem is to use one token for a call of an object member -- i.e. entire `a.b.c` must be a single token.

You may also refer to automatic parser generators for another solution of your problem. They allow to define complete  grammar of your target language (JavaScript) as a set of formal rules and generate parser automatically. List of popular tools includes tools that generates parser on different programming languages: [ANTLR, Bison + Lex, Lemon + Ragel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generators#Parser_development_software).

--artem

Comment: `.` is as much of a single token an operator as `+`.

Comment: @delnan is right. We should treat dot just like a normal operator.

Answer (score 0):

(I saw this question is still alive. I found the solution for it myself.)

First I threat the `(...)` and `[...]` expressions as one token and expand them (recursively) when needed. Then I detect the function calls and array subscripts. If there isn't an infix operator before a parenthesized token, then that's a function call or an array subscript, so I insert a special call-function or access operator there. With this modification it works like charm.